# conditions for Convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions

Suppose $\{f_n\}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence of a positive real-valued functions defined on
$[0, T]$ and continuous on $(0, T)$. If {$f_n$} satisfies the following conditions :

1. $f_n( iT/2^n ) = g( iT/2^n ) ,\,  i = 0, 1,\ldots, 2^n$.
2. $f_n$ is differentiable on ($ i/2^n, (i+1)/2^n $), $\,i = 0, 1,\ldots, 2n − 1.$

then $f_n$ converges to g on $[0, T]$

I know the above claim is wrong. (The sine function is one of the counter examples)

Which conditions should be added to make the claim valid?

And how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

For example: the derivatives $f'_n$ satisfy $\sup|f'(t)|\le M$, where $M$ is independent of $n$, and $g$ is continuous on $[0,T]$. Then, for $t\in(i/2^n,(i+1)/2^n)$,
$$
 |f_n(t)-g(t)|\le |f_n(t)-f_n(i/2^n)|+|g(t)-f_n(i/2^n)|=|f_n(t)-f_n(i/2^n)|+|g(t)-g(i/2^n)|\le
M/2^n +\delta_g(1/2^n),
$$
where $\delta_g(\tau)=\sup_{|t-t'|\le\tau}|g(t)-g(t')|$ is the modulus of continuity of $g$. Since $g$ is continuous and hence uniformly continuous on $[0,T]$, we have $\delta_g(\tau)\xrightarrow{\tau\to0}0$, and we see that $f_n\to g$ uniformly on $[0,T]$.